# How can I Inject two or more dependencies with the same interface?

Tags: c#, autofac

Consider the following code

```
public interface ISomeInterface
{
    void DoSomething();
}

public class A : ISomeInterface
{
    public void DoSomething() { }
}

public class B : ISomeInterface
{
    public void DoSomething() { }
}
```

And then one class using 2 interfaces:

```
public class C : IC
{
    protected ISomeInterface _dependency1;
    protected ISomeInterface _dependency2;

    public C ( ISomeInterface dependency1, ISomeInterface dependency2 )
    {
        _dependency1 = dependency1;
        _dependency2 = dependency2;
    }
}
```

I would like to inject A in dependency1 and B in dependency2. I know I can do something like that:

```
builder.RegisterType<C>().As<IC>()
    .WithParameter( "dependency1", new A() )
    .WithParameter( "dependency2", new B() );
```

But I know there is a better way to do it with Autofac.

Comment: have you tried an array or an `IEnumerable<ISomInterface>`?

Comment: that could work, but imagine i have lots of objects implementing ISomeInterface and lots of objects consuming only a few set of them. And worst, I will be implementing some in the future. Then, in the comsumers I would like to be transparent in the number of ISomeInteefaces. Whith ninject I can put a name-attribute before each parameter and then make the binding with that name. I woult loke to do something like this with Autofac.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you register your `ISomeInterface` implantations you can give [them a name](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/TypedNamedAndKeyedServices):

```
containerBuilder.RegisterType<A>().Named<ISomeInterface>("A");
containerBuilder.RegisterType<B>().Named<ISomeInterface>("B");
```

Then you can register your `C` to resolve it's arguments with using the defined names:

```
containerBuilder.Register(c =>
    new C(c.ResolveNamed<ISomeInterface>("A"), 
        c.ResolveNamed<ISomeInterface>("B")))
    .As<IC>();
```

With using the above code you have to specify all the constructor parameters of `C` even when some parameters don't need "named" registrations.

So if you only want to specify the "named" parameters you can use the `WithParameter` together the resolving:

```
containerBuilder.RegisterType<C>().As<IC>()
    .WithParameter((p, c) => p.Name == "dependency1", 
                   (p, c) => c.ResolveNamed<ISomeInterface>("A"))
    .WithParameter((p, c) => p.Name == "dependency2", 
                   (p, c) => c.ResolveNamed<ISomeInterface>("B"));
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, why would you like to inject two instances of the same interface? It must be something that differentiate them?

My suggestion is that you register two sub interfaces, ie. ISomeInterface1 : ISomeInterface ISomeInterface2 : ISomeInterface and inject those two. Then you don't have to deal with the named parameters.

Comment: that will work. But I am not looking on a solution here, I am looking for the best possible solution. I am trying to master Autofac :-)